# Drawing a circle / arc on top of an image in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a simple canvas with a rectangle as the background, an image at the bottom and I'm trying to draw a circle that has a part overlapping the image. I'm a bit stuck on which `globalCompositeOperation` to use such that the arc/circle appears on top of the image on the canvas.

Code:

```js
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 70;

      context.fillStyle = "#29BEF1";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 131);

       var img = new Image;
       img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/aN26XpH.png';

       img.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(img, 0, 29)
      } 

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(800, -29, 87, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStyle = '#FEDB62';
      context.fill();
```

```css
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
```

```html
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="131"></canvas>
```

Comment: its an async issue, plop the code which is under `img.onload` into the `img.onload` event (under the existing line)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you! If you could post it as an answer so I can mark it as such that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused as loading an image is asynchronous, then once loaded and drawn it overlaps what's already drawn.

A solution is to move the code which is drawing the sun into the `onload` callback.

```
img.onload = function() {
  // draw image
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 29)

  // draw sun
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(800, -29, 87, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = '#FEDB62';
  context.fill();
}
```